# Fragment with CheckBox

Tags: java, android

I have three Fragments and in all three Fragments I used CheckBoxes I want that when the fragment switches, the checkboxes remains as it is.

```
Button.OnClickListener btnOnClickListener=new Button.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(android.view.View v) {
      Fragment newFragment;
      if(v==btn1){
          newFragment=new AwardTypeFragment();
      }else if(v==btn2){
          newFragment =new StateFragment();
      }else if(v==btn3){
          newFragment= new CityFragment();
      }else if(v==btn4){
          newFragment=new GenderFragment();
      }else{
          newFragment=new StartFragment();
      }                 
      FragmentTransaction transaction=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
      transaction.replace(R.id.myFragment, newFragment);
      transaction.addToBackStack(null);     
      transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
      transaction.commit();             
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Store the state of the checkboxes in the activity.  When a checkbox is selected, call something like:

```
getActivity().setCheckbox1State(true);
```

Similarly, get the state with:

```
getActivity().getCheckbox1State();
```

Replace the Checkbox1 name reference with the actual value that it represents.  In the activity, you will need to implement both the get and set methods.  This is a simple example; you can create a more elegant interface that handles all the checkboxes and saves the state.

Answer (score -1):

//In the Oncreate of Fragment Constructor

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
.... 

View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

CheckBox favoritosBox = (CheckBox) root.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxFav);

favoritosBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, 
                                 boolean isChecked) {
        //ACTION
    }
});
```